# IOS weather app

Tags: ios

I want to use google api for iOS weather api. But I found out that it is down. Even the google awareness app api is available only for android. What to do? Is there a way to use google api for making weather api in iOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not use google weather api for iOS. You can use Yahoo Weather Api

[Weather Api](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)